# Подключение к postgres поднятому в докере

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

запустим:

```
docker-compose up
```

Я думал, что после проделанных манипуляций я смогу подключиться к `postgress` указав в качестве хоста `localhost`. (Под подключением я имею ввиду подключение не заходя в докер контейнер)  Однако такой способ не сработает, при подключении будет ошибка

```
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist
```

Погуглив я нашел правильный способ подключения - не надо использовать `localhost`, вместо этого надо использовать адрес, полученный с помощью команды

```
ifconfig -u | grep 'inet ' | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2 | head -1
```

Хоть подключиться у меня и получилось, осталось непонимание ситуации. Почему не работает подключение по `localhost`? Почему работает второй описанный мной способ? В чем вообще смысл команды `ifconfig -u | grep 'inet ' | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | cut -d\  -f2 | head -1`?

У меня macos

Comment: А какая у Вас OS? Судя по всему не windows. Либо запускаете docker в WSL (об этом тоже нет инфы) Если мак, то можно использовать "host.docker.internal:5432"

Comment: @Vein macos. Я хочу подключится не заходя в сам контейнер. Насколько я понимаю ```host.docker.internal``` работает именно внутри контейнера. Добавил инфу в вопрос

Comment: Есть `postgres` установленный вне докера?

Comment: @MaksimAlekseev нет

Comment: Хм, тогда почему появляется такая ошибка не подскажу, а как решить проблему дал ответ.

Comment: Если вы хотите подключиться к базе данных извне то прокиньте порт наружу, если вы хотите использовать контейнер в другом контейнере на одном сетевом уровне, то укажите в качестве адреса название контейнера и желаемый порт

Comment: @MoloF я изначально прокидывал порт наружу. Но видимо этот порт был занят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы подключиться к базе созданной в `docker-e` из вне, нужно прокинуть порт в сервиce `docker-compose`:

```
ports:
  - "13000:5432"
```

Теперь будет доступно подключение к базе внутри контейнера - `localhost:13000`

Test:

```py
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname='db',
    user='user',
    password='password',
    host='localhost',
    port=13000
)

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT datname FROM pg_database;')
print(*cursor.fetchall())

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Output:

```
('postgres',) ('db',) ('template1',) ('template0',)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Странная ситуация, видимо я не до конца удалил постгрес, либо на порту 5432 было что-то другое. Но смена порта на 13000 помогла